# Xamarin: Launch youtube channel in youtube app

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to open a youtube channel in youtube app in xamarin forms. I am able to open the specific facebook page and twitter page by writing these lines of code:

```
Device.OpenUri(new Uri("fb://page/page_id"));
Device.OpenUri(new Uri("twitter://user?user_id=userid"));
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840774/intent-to-youtube-app-profile-channel) for android and I tried this:

```
Device.OpenUri(new Uri("vnd.youtube://channel_id"));
```

But I am getting 400 network error after being launched in youtube application. Is there another way to open the youtube profile/channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering to my question:

```
Device.OpenUri(new Uri("vnd.youtube://user/XamarinVideos"));
```

This directly launch the youtube channel in the youtube app if installed in device.